# XSL Selecting the Nth field

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to the XSL and have this question, so I have this XML

```
<a>  
  <b>
    <c1>
      <d>N1</d>
      <e>Test</e>
    </c1>
    <c1>
      <d>N1</d>
      <e>Test2</e>
    </c1>
   </b>
 </a>
```

So I want to get the value test2 so, here is my statement, which it doesnt work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//b/c1[2]">
    <xsl:if test="d = N1">
        <data>
            <xsl:value-of select="e"/> 
        </data>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source XML contains some mistakes.

The first thing to correct is to change `<e>Test/<e>` to `<e>Test</e>`
(the slash should be after `<`, to form the closing tag.

Then look at `<xsl:for-each select="//b/c1[2]">` in your XSLT.
`c1[2]` means that you want the **second** element with `c1` name.

So the secont thing to change is change `<c2> ... </c2>` to
`<c1> ... </c1>`, thus you will have the second `c1` element.

As a result, your source XML should be as follows:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>
      <d>N1</d>
      <e>Test</e>
    </c1>
    <c1>
      <d>N1</d>
      <e>Test2</e>
    </c1>
  </b>
</a>
```

Another important thing is that you cannot start the XSLT script
with just `<xsl:for-each...`.

You must start with `<xsl:stylesheet` as the main tag.

Then, e.g. in a template matching `/` there shoud be placed
some main tag (I called it just `main`, see below), and
**within it** there can be placed your `for-each` loop.

The next correction pertains to `<xsl:if test="d = N1">`.
Change it to `<xsl:if test="d = 'N1'">`, because `N1` is a
**string constant**, not a tag name.

So the whole XSLT script can be e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <main>
      <xsl:for-each select="//b/c1[2]">
        <xsl:if test="d = 'N1'">
          <data>
            <xsl:value-of select="e"/>
          </data>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </main>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
   <data>Test2</data>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to chase down all the issues with OP's question.  (+1)

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I have already fixed those issues, and I didn't think namespace is necessary for my question, since it won't affect the answer, and I wanted a quick response.
Thanks for your answer.